# Trying to create subtasks in sharepoint using javascript, but clientContext seems to be returning [object object]

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Everything I've seen online basically does the same thing when trying to create subtasks; it starts by getting the current clientcontext, then by getting the task list you want to create a new subtask for.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyTaskList1');
```

My issue is, oList doesn't seem to be populating correctly. Or maybe I just don't know what it is supposed to be. I tried to parse what the value of clientyContext and oList were while running the code, using alert(clientContext) and alert(oList) but both of those returned as [object Object] which I have no idea is correct or not.

Really, I just have no idea if I'm even on the right track here. Is there a different way to see what the current value of a variable is?

Comment: You could try `alert(JSON.stringify(oList, null, 2));` but it would be better to use the dev tools an take a look at things in the console.

Comment: and on the case for your oList, it is because it might be outside the current context, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Tasks have a hidden column called **ParentID**, you can't see this column when you try to edit the list view but it is available in every Task list.

If you want to create sub-tasks, just add the new row and set the ParentID to the same ID from the top task you want to use, you will establish a relationship for the sub-tasks.

The functions below will let you create new tasks (PARENT) and also the sub-tasks (CHILDREN), for example:

```
NewTask('Bug List'); // create the PARENT TASK, e.g. ID=15
NewSubTask(15, 'Add Try..Catch'); // sub-task for ParentID=15
NewSubTask(15, 'Recompile code'); // another sub-task
```

[image]

Here is the fully functional code for the solution above:

```
function NewTask(taskName)
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', taskName);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function NewSubTask(parentID, taskName)
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('ParentID', parentID);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', taskName);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded()
{
    console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The functions above work on the current context, but you can point to any direction by simply changing the following:

```
// uses the current context 
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

// point to an specific URL
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/MySiteCollection');
```